# Is there a font which supports invisible chararcter and has every character at the same size?

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I'm a newbie in android developpement and ASCII art.
I made an RPG which uses ASCII art for graphics but I can't find any font which, when applied to Android :
-Supports invisible characters;
-Has a unique size for all characters, including every character in UTF-8.

Unfortunately I foud Consolas which works well on PC, not in Android.

Could you please help me?

PS - One of the concerned ASCII-arts :
[ASCII art](https://gyazo.com/bb989197e6e71eac268ca3285ad9e590)

EDIT - Nevermind, I found that Courier new works well. I just need to find another invisible character.;.

Comment: Are you looking for fixed width font - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076599/whats-happened-to-monospace-in-android-lollipop

Comment: yes, that was that
Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Use `Spannable` - it can be set invisible. Or use `InputFilter` to filter out something (replace with spaces)