# TextView - monospaced font

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to set a TextView to use monospaced font. A seemingly trivial task (and I've been developing for Android since 2010) but alas I must be missing something.

This keeps the default font, definitely not monospaced:

```
mOutputText.typeface = Typeface.MONOSPACE
...
private lateinit var mOutputText: TextView
```

Tried this too:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_log"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff0f0f0"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Same thing, the text view retains the default - non-monospaced - font.

I have these in my dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
```

Am I perhaps seeing some strange artifact of using Google's Material library?

How do I set a TextView's font to monospaced in 2023?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109277/9722336